# Custom Appbar's animation Flutter

Tags: flutter-layout

I want to make app bar with animation like this. Any ideas?

[GIF](https://giphy.com/gifs/TgVDOF2KD0s2OIVsle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html) For the animation you want to create,

```
 SliverAppBar(
      expandedHeight: height,
      flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: Text('Reading Now'),
      ),
```

For more details you can visit [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9C5KMJKluE)

Comment: Thank you so much!!